# Expanding a multi-dimensional array variable inside a variable

Tags: php, arrays

```
$content="The value of this variable is {$array['1']['value']}"
```

I have to do this multiple times within many paragraphs for different mutli-dimensional array values. Can't seem to find the answer online. Thank you!

Edit:

I have a multi dimensional array currently being posted to the page I am posting the array to, so lets say I wanted to get the value that is currently in:
 $array['1']['thisvalue']

In  the same file I have a variable $content:
I am using $content to store text from an article. In this article in the $content variable, I have some fill in the blanks which I will use the array value *($array['1']['thisvalue'])* to fill in. so for example:

$content="my name is_____ and my height is ____"

$array['1']['thisvalue'] would contain my name and $array['2']['thisvalue'] would contain my height

so

$content="my name is *$array['1']['thisvalue']* and my height is *$array['2']['thisvalue']*"

Then at the end of filling in all the blanks I have

```
file_put_contents($file, $content);
```

$file is a file I have generated in another directory, and I am putting the contents into the file.

MY QUESTION IS:

How do I use my multidimensional arrays to fill in the blanks of my article so that it will expand with the correct values when i write to this separate $file file.

Comment: What is the question???

Comment: Before you try to `expanding a multi-dimensional array variable inside a variable`, expand your question.

Answer (score 0):

A [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) or any other kind of loop will do the work for you.

i.e. :

**Array :**

```
print_r($arr);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [some_key] => Something
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [some_key] => Another Something
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [some_key] => Again Another Something
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [some_key] => Something Else
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [some_key] => Need more imagination...
        )

)
```

**Loop :**

```
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    echo $item['some_key'] . "\n";
}
```

**Output :**

> ```
> Something
> Another Something
> Again Another Something
> Something Else
> Need more imagination...
> ```